# How to get max Id of items on Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My DB :
[image]

I create new item like this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(Api.CREDITS).child(String.valueOf(item.getId())).setValue(item);
```

but when I'll create a new item , I need to set his ID... how to determinate last id of items in the list in Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probable:

```
var latest = ref.child("credits").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
latest.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String latestKey = childSnapshot.getKey();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
})
```

But this is going to lead to problems like:

- this operation will not work when the user is without network connectivity
- when multiple users are trying to add children at (almost) the same time

This is one of the many reasons why Firebase recommends against using such sequential numeric IDs and uses push IDs.

Read the [documentation on dealing with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists) and this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html